# Multiply columns in different dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr, multidplyr

I am writing a code for analysis a set of dplyr data.

here is how my table_1 looks:

```
 1 A B C
 2 5 2 3
 3 9 4 1
 4 6 3 8
 5 3 7 3
```

And my table_2 looks like this:

```
 1 D E F
 2 2 9 3
```

I would love to based on table 1 column"A", if A>6, then create a column "G" in table1, equals to "`C*D+C*E`"

Basically, it's like make table 2 as a factor...

Is there any way I can do it?

I can apply a filter to Column "A" and multiply Column"C" with a set number instead of a factor from table_2

```
 table_1_New <- mutate(Table_1,G=if_else(A<6,C*2+C*9))
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output? also in case `table_2` have multiple rows which row would you take to multiply ?

Comment: HI Ronak, Thank you for the help. I think the output i would love to archive is looks like table 1 but with 1 extra column"G". And G is equals to C*2+C*9. which is the same number from table_2. It like multiply column "C" with a vector (Row2 in table2）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
#Initialize G column with 0
df1$G <- 0
#Get index where A value is greater than 6
inds <- df1$A > 6
#Multiply those values with D and E from df2
df1$G[inds] <- df1$C[inds] * df2$D + df1$C[inds] * df2$E
df1

#  A B C  G
#2 5 2 3  0
#3 9 4 1 11
#4 6 3 8  0
#5 3 7 3  0
```

Using `dplyr`, we can do

```
df1 %>% mutate(G = ifelse(A > 6, C*df2$D + C*df2$E, 0))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah, Thank you for helping me , but it does not work, it saids: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: @BomberGay Can you try `df1 %>% mutate(G = ifelse(A > 6, C*df2$D[1] + C*df2$E[1], 0))`